# my custom keyboardview is not showed in my layout

Tags: android, view, scrollview, horizontalscrollview

i have a problem with my custom keyboard view inside ScrollView and HorizontalScrollView. In particular my keyboard is not showed but the other components as some text view are displayed normally. My layout:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/miolayout2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/back_lavagna"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:textAlignment="center" >

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/miolayout3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/miolayout1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:editable="false"
                android:ems="10" >

                <requestFocus />
            </EditText>

            <android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView
                android:id="@+id/keyboardView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:background="#aabbcc"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                android:visibility="visible" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/risultato1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="risultato1"
                android:textColor="#456"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/risultato2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="risultato1"
                android:textColor="#076"
                android:textSize="22sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/risultato3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="risultato1"
                android:textColor="#219"
                android:textSize="24sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/risultato4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="risultato1"
                android:textColor="#006"
                android:textSize="28sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/risultato5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="risultato1 adsfdsg bdsfsd sdgfsd dsfgsd sdgfsf dsaffds"
                android:textColor="#400"
                android:textSize="30sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>

</ScrollView>
```

If i delete the HorizontalScrollView all seems ok, and my custom keyboard is showed.
This is my onCreate method of my class:

```
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_keyboard_main);

            keyboardView = (KeyboardView) findViewById(R.id.keyboardView);
            Typeface type = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
                    "fonts/DS-DIGI.TTF");

            keyboard = new Keyboard(this, R.xml.keyboard_querty);
            keyboardView.setKeyboard(keyboard);
            keyboardView.setEnabled(true);
            keyboardView.setPreviewEnabled(true);
            keyboardView.setOnKeyListener((android.view.View.OnKeyListener) this);
            keyboardView.setOnKeyboardActionListener(this);                
            keyCodeMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
            keyCodeMap.put("1", "1");
            keyCodeMap.put("2", "2");
            keyCodeMap.put("3", "3");
            keyCodeMap.put("4", "+");
            keyCodeMap.put("5", "4");
            keyCodeMap.put("6", "5");
            keyCodeMap.put("7", "6");
            keyCodeMap.put("8", "-");
            keyCodeMap.put("9", "7");
            keyCodeMap.put("10", "8");
            keyCodeMap.put("11", "9");
            keyCodeMap.put("12", "I");
            keyCodeMap.put("13", "x");
            keyCodeMap.put("14", "0");
            keyCodeMap.put("15", "t");
            keyCodeMap.put("16", ".");
            currentEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
            currentEditText.setTypeface(type);
            currentEditText.setText(Html.fromHtml(" P(X)="));
            currentEditText.setCursorVisible(false);
            currentEditText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

             public void onClick(View v) {
                     toggleKeyboardVisibility(currentEditText);
             }
             });
        }
```

what's wrong?
I need a layout able to scroll both horizontal and vertical, because a component in a dynamic manner may be larger than the size of the screen.

Thanks in Advance